# hover image <div> is moved up in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, hover

My divs are are getting shoved upward when I view my page in Chrome. I can't understand why it's fine in Firefox, but once I load the page in Chrome, IE, or MS Edge, it's moved up about 15px.

I apologize if this is improper way of sharing HTML/CSS codes but here it is:

```
.tw {
background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/tyrNFnz.png); 
repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
background-position: bottom left;
display: block;
width: 131px;
height: 159px;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -1879px;
margin-left: -192px;
z-index: 4;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
-webkit-transition: .4s all ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: .4s all ease-in-out;
-o-transition: .4s all ease-in-out;
transition: .4s all ease-in-out;
}

.tw:hover {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Where is HTML Code? Suggest you create snippet in the question or share it via jsfiddle/codepen/etc.

Comment: I don't think fiddle would be good to demonstrate. It's an artist page for my account to Soundclick.com. Here is my page www.thejetzons.com

Comment: I just think it's too much coding for me to paste here, the HTML I am allowed to enter is pasted in a bio section "About Me" of our user account page. I'll paste that, but just know that I don't have access to 99% of the HTML because it belongs to the Soundclick website, my page is just one of many artists pages that belong to the main website.

Comment: It says this next to the section we're allowed to insert our HTML coding: 
" Please note
You may use simple html tags or
link to images.
The standard html link looks like this
<a href="http://www.myLink.com">my link</a>
Please do not use any script in your code!"

Comment: Plz show your html with jsfiddle